# creating a jar for a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am using Eclipse and I have just started working on a project that needs another project (say *pjkt*) to function. The *pjkt* project files are stored in a specific folder. I would like to create a jar from *pjkt* and then add this jar to my project buildpath. How do I do this? Do I need create first in Eclipse a new project from the *pjkt* code, build it and then select the *export* command?

Answer (score 0):

Yes create a new project and export as .jar.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about the build path:

- Create a project directory (in the using project) for library files - it's common to create it in parallel to `/src` and `/bin` and call it `/lib`;
- Once you've created (by exporting) your jar from the used project, copy it into the `/lib` directory;
- If you did any of this creating and copying outside of eclipse, refresh your project so everything will show up in the Project Explorer;
- In the Project Explorer, right-click on the .jar in the `/lib` folder and do "Build Path | Add to Build Path".

Done!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work on both projects, and have them open in Eclipse at the same time, another approach is to open Properties -> Build Path for the new project, and add pjkt on the Project Dependencies tab.  This will provide all the exported resources from pjkt to the master project.